# Split JS string based on multiple different RegExr conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JS string, say:

```
var testString = "words here, svg_icon('Var-1') svg_icon('Var_2'), and even more words here";
```

I understand how to match the string based on a fixed value e.g. if I want to match on `svg_icon`:

```js
var testString = "words here, svg_icon('Var-1','var_3') svg_icon('Var_2'), and even more words here";
var filterMatch = /(svg_icon)/;
var results = testString.match(filterMatch);

results.forEach((result) => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

This logs the 2 matches it finds, which I'm expecting:

```
"svg_icon"
"svg_icon"
```

What I'm trying to do is match the expression so my output will be:

```
"svg_icon('Var-1','var_3')"
"svg_icon('Var_2')"
```

I *think* this is possible with Regular expressions, but cannot find how to deal with combining conditions whilst matching the changing "variable" names (e.g.`'Var-1','var_3'` and `Var_2`) that may contain special characters (just dashes and underscores).

Any help on what RegEx I can use in this situation, or if this is in fact possible with so many conditions.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

Match the `(` through `)` after `svg_icon`.

You need to use the `g` modifier to match multiple times. You're just matching the first `svg_icon` -- you're getting two outputs because `match[0]` is the full match, and `match[1]` is the capture group.

```js
var testString = "words here, svg_icon('Var-1','var_3') svg_icon('Var_2'), and even more words here";
var filterMatch = /svg_icon\([^)]*\)/g;
var results = testString.match(filterMatch);

results.forEach((result) => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, thank you for the explanation behind it as well!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
svg_icon\('[vV][aA][rR][\-_]\d+'(?:,'[vV][aA][rR][\-_]\d+')*\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/WctF2Q/1

Comment: Why not use the `i` flag instead of things like `[vV]`?

Answer (score 1):

Change regex to `/svg_icon.+?\)/g`

https://regex101.com/r/3zBfDq/1

| Segment | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `svg_icon` | Match literal "svg_icon"... |
| `.` | ...then anything but a new line... |
| `+` | ...for one to an unlimited amount of occurrences... |
| `?\)` | ...until the first closing parenthesis (escaped with `\`). |

Add a `g`lobal flag which is required to use `.matchAll()` (`.match()` on steroids):

```js
var testString = "words here, svg_icon('Var-1','var_3') svg_icon('Var_2'), and even more words here";
var filterMatch = /svg_icon.+?\)/g;
var result = [...testString.matchAll(filterMatch)].flat();
console.log(`Result is an array of matches:`);
console.log(result);
console.log(`Access a single match like so:`);
console.log(`First match is: result[0]`);
console.log(result[0]);
console.log(`Second match is: result[1]`)
console.log(result[1]);
```

```css
.as-console-row::after { width: 0; font-size: 0; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; word-break: break-word; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; min-width: 100%; }
```

The signature is just like `.match()` but you'll need to wrap everything into square brackets `[]` and use the spread operator `...` and then flatten it with `.flat()`. The result is an array of matches.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, I didn't consider having the results in an array, but that actually suits my use case a lot better.

Comment: Do you need to say "or whitespace"? Whitespace is implied by "any character". `.` matches anything except newline.